# add jquery file if a certain page is included

Tags: theme-development, templates, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I was wondering if anyone could help my by explaining if it is possible to enqueue a javascript file only if for example homepage.php is included.

what i have tried to do inside homepage.php:

```
class homepage_js {
static $add_script;

static function init() {
    add_action('init', array(__CLASS__, 'register_script'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array(__CLASS__, 'print_script'));
}

static function register_script() {
    wp_register_script('my-script', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}

static function print_script() {
    if ( ! self::$add_script )
        return;

    wp_print_scripts('my-script');
}
}

homepage_js::init();
```

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

While you can approach it with "what template is loaded", WP isn't engineered for such logic. Template load is *result* of logic processing, not the other way around.

You should check out [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) and determine which logical check applies to your situation.

Other than that you should be:

- running script-related logic on appropriate `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook
- let WP handle footer load (which you are doing via registartion), need for explicit print is extremely rare

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution that comes to mind, is actually en-queueing the script within the file needed, or within a function that gets called only in that file. If `wp_enqueue_script()` is run after `wp_head()`, it gets en-queued in the footer.